# Compiling for Mac OS X using Delphi XE2

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

1) I can only add Windows 64 bit as a target platform.
**How do I compile for Mac OS X?**

2) I want the app to scan through the files on the hard drive and copy them.

**Do I need permission from Apple to do this? Some sort of license or something? If so how do I acquire it?**

Comment: Embarcadero is an unnecessary tag. It's like adding the tag `Microsoft` for SQL Server or Windows API questions, or `Apple` for questions about OS X (you didn't need that in your text, either - OS X is *only* Mac, so you can save some typing <g>).

Comment: Well this is several questions in one go. What edition of Delphi XE2 are you using? (Starter/Pro/Etc).   Secondly, did you create a VCL or a firemonkey app? Firemonkey is cross platform, and can have Mac OS X as a target. VCL can not. So you are probably working in a VCL app and that's your first thing.  You better go read some docs!

Comment: Did you install the Mac OS compiler? I know I didn't and I cannot create a Mac target.

Comment: As for question 2, that really should be a separate question. It would be much better if you asked it as such. If you want to know what you can do with the files on your Mac, ask Apple, or read the license that you accepted when you installed OSX.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I use the Architect version. I will try doing all of the above.

Comment: The platform should be available on architect version if you are building a firemonkey app.  If not, you may have an install problem.  I recently had to reinstall update 4 because the 32bit windows compiler was missing (even though the 64 bit and OSX compilers were in place).  If you need to go down this path, you also need to be sure to delete all registry settings.  I reinstalled a couple of times without doing this and it did not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only compile Firemonkey projects for OSX.
If you start out with a VCL project, it will be linked to Windows only, because VCL is tied to the Windows API, whereas Firemonkey is cross-platform.

Start a new project:

File -> New -> FireMonkey HD Application

[image: Right click]

Right click on target platform (choose Add Platform...)

[image: Choose OS X]

And choose OS X.

> Do I need permission from Apple to do this? Some sort of license or something? If so how do I acquire it?

Following the instructions here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Mac_OS_X_Application_Development